# Установка цели метрики на событие копирования в буфер обмена

Tags: javascript, яндекс-метрика

Необходима настройка цели метрики на событие которое срабатывает при выделении и копировании адреса электронной почты в буфер обмена, куда можно повешать данный код?

Суть проблемы в том, что при анализе вэбвизора выяснили что посетители не хотят отправлять форму обратной связи а просто копируют адрес электронной почты на сайте, как нам это отловить для цели метрики?

Comment: Установить oncopy event на элемент в котором находится адрес почты. Event реагирует на копирование. Это вы хотели узнать?

Comment: да, благодарю=_)